# Kann ein Ansatz Probleme haben?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, noun

Zum Beispiel:

> Ich habe einen Ansatz entwickelt, der das Fliegen ohne künstliche Hilfen ermöglicht. Er hat jedoch einige **Probleme**. Unter anderem ist es bisher nicht möglich, mehr als etwa einen Meter an Höhe zu gewinnen und bei der Landung fehlt es an Möglichkeiten von der Fluggeschwindigkeit kontrolliert zum Stehen zu kommen.

Kann man hier von *Problemen* sprechen oder welches Wort ist besser geeignet?

Comment: Neben dem Vorschlag von @timbo, kann man auch von "Mängeln", "Fehlern", "Defiziten", "Macken" sprechen. Es gibt mit Sicherheit noch eine handvoll weiterer Wörter. Aber im Grunde kann ein jedes Wort, was darauf hinweist, dass eine Funktionalität fehlt oder defekt ist, kann hier sinnvoll verwendet werden.

Comment: Oder "Er hat noch Entwicklungspotenzial" ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: "Wir haben einen hervorragenden Ansatz mit reichlich Entwicklungspotenzial." - das kann man als Möglichkeit oder als Notwendigkeit sehen, super Idee ;)

Comment: Das Wort 'Ansatz' sagt bereits, dass es nicht fertig ist. Dem widerspricht aber das 'ermöglicht'. Entweder Du kannst ohne künstliche Hilfe fliegen, oder Du hast nur einen Ansatz dazu, kannst es also noch nicht. "Ich habe einen Ansatz zum Fliegen ohne künstliche Hilfe entwickelt." Punkt. Würde der Ansatz das Fliegen schon ermöglichen, dann wäre es kein Ansatz mehr. Der Ansatz hat auch nicht die Probleme, sondern Du. Vielleicht Du mit dem Ansatz. Er bringt einige Probleme mit sich.

Comment: `Das Wort 'Ansatz' sagt` Wörter können nichts sagen. `Er bringt einige Probleme mit sich` Ansätze sind abstrakte Konzepte, die nicht mit sich bringen könnnen. Natürliche Sprache ist gespikt mit Metaphern und Redewendungen. Die Ausführungen des Ansatzes sollten präzise und unmissverständlich sein, aber ich finde, in der Metadiskussion über den Ansatz kann man ruhig über seine Probleme sprechen.

Answer (score 10):

Also ich würde eher sagen

> Er hat jedoch einige Schwächen.

oder auch

> Es gibt [mit ihm] jedoch einige Probleme.

Die Formulierung mit dem Ansatz, der Probleme hat, klingt (für meine bescheidenen Ohren) nicht ganz richtig -- aber auch nicht unbedingt total falsch.

Comment: Ich stimme voll zu. Ich denke, dass solche Formulierungen total weit verbreitet sind aber ein Lektor würde es vielleicht anstreichen.

Answer (score 8):

'schulligung, aber ich rate ab von "einen Ansatz entwickeln". Vorsicht bei der Aneinanderreihung abstrakter Begriffe (Ansatz + entwickeln), das klingt schnell hohl. Alternativen:

> - Ich arbeite daran, das Fliegen ohne Hilfsmittel zu ermöglichen. Dabei treten jedoch Schwierigkeiten auf.
> - Ich möchte dem Menschen das Fliegen beibringen. Leider funktioniert das noch nicht wie gewünscht.
> - Meine FuE-Tätigkeit soll Menschen in die Lage versetzen, aus eigener Kraft zu fliegen. Allerdings bin ich dabei auf einige Probleme gestoßen.

Wenn es unbedingt etwas mit Ansatz sein soll:

> Bei meinen Versuchen, ohne Hilfsmittel zu fliegen, hat sich mein
>   bisheriger Ansatz als problematisch herausgestellt.

Wichtig bei der letzten Variante ist, dass **Ansatz** nach hinten verschoben wird. Zuerst kommt das Vorhaben, erst dann der darin verfolgte Ansatz. Anders herum wirkt es verkehrt. Worin der Ansatz nun besteht, ist eine wichtige Information, die daher nicht fehlen sollte:

> Bei meinen Versuchen, ohne Hilfsmittel zu fliegen, hat sich mein
>   bisheriger Ansatz als problematisch herausgestellt. Ein kräftiger
>   Absprung und heftige Armbewegungen alleine sind nicht so effektiv wie
>   erwartet. Unter anderem ist es bisher nicht möglich, mehr als etwa
>   einen Meter an Höhe zu gewinnen, und bei der Landung habe ich noch
>   keinen Weg gefunden, aus der Flugphase heraus kontrolliert zum Stehen
>   zu kommen.

---

In einem Kommentar wird moniert, ich hätte die Frage nicht beantwortet. Das sehe ich anders, aber bitte, hier noch eine weitere Variante, dieses Mal mit den beiden Substantiven "Ansatz" und "Problem".

> In meinen Versuchsreihen zum Fliegen ohne Hilfsmittel habe ich
>   kräftiges Abspringen mit heftigem Armrudern kombiniert. Das Problem
>   bei diesem Ansatz ist, dass die Probanden nicht über einen Meter Höhe
>   hinauskommen, auch ist so kein sicherer Stand bei der Landung zu
>   erreichen.

---

Update 2013-01-11 19:56 UTC

Der Beispieltext des Fragestellers war meiner Ansicht nach nicht glücklich gewählt. Wie "user unknown" im derzeit vierten Kommentar unterhalb der Frage zutreffend anmerkt, ist es ungünstig zu schreiben, ein Ansatz ermögliche etwas. Allenfalls **soll** ein Ansatz etwas ermöglichen. Das sind eben so die Fallstricke, die lauern, wenn man mit abstrakten Begriffen hantiert. Darüber hinaus ist "einen Ansatz entwickeln" auch gefährlich nahe an (unsinniger) Redundanz, d. h. "einen Ansatz ansetzen" oder "eine Entwicklung entwickeln". Wohl gemerkt, es ist nicht *genau* doppelt gemoppelt, aber unangenehm nahe daran.

Zwei Faustregeln helfen, solche Fallstricke zu vermeiden:

1. **Einfach schreiben.** Wann immer ich die Wahl habe zwischen abstrakten Begriffen und Worten aus der Alltagssprache, entscheide
   ich mich für letztere. (Wenn allerdings abstrakte Begriffe gefordert
   sind, müssen sie auch verwendet werden.)
2. **Endkontrolle.** Hängt alles gut zusammen und ergibt es einen Sinn? Wenn mein Text eine Spielzeugeisenbahn wäre, würde ein Zug von A nach B fahren können oder an einer Weiche entgleisen? Sich den Text vorzulesen, kann
   helfen.

Werden diese beiden Faustregeln befolgt, kann meiner Meinung nach so etwas wie "der Ansatz hat ein Problem" erst gar nicht geschrieben werden. Ich habe es vermieden zu sagen, "Nein, `der Ansatz hat ein Problem` geht überhaupt nicht". Ich weiß ja nicht, ob diese Aussage überall und zu allen Zeiten gültig ist, eventuell kommt einer mit einem Text, in dem es eben doch passt. So sind sie eben, die natürlichen Sprachen :)

Comment: Sorry, aber das beantwortet nicht die eigentliche Frage, sondern nur, wie man dem "Problem" aus dem Weg gehen kann.

Comment: @En1: Ich finde die Formulierungen durchweg besser als in der Frage. Ich würde nur noch weiter gehen, und das "ermöglichen" noch rauswerfen: "Ich arbeite daran, ohne Hilfsmittel zu fliegen." Wieso ermöglichen? Wenn der andere das Motorflugzeug hat, und Du das Benzin, ja, dann ermöglicht man anderen zu fliegen.

Comment: @userunknown Dass die Formulierungen besser sind, stelle ich auch gar nicht zur Diskussion. Ich sage nur, dass die eigentliche Frage nicht beantwortet ist. Und die Ergänzung klärt die Frage ja auch nicht. Wenn ein "Problem bei einem Ansatz" existiert, hat der Ansatz das Problem oder ist das Problem nur bei dem Ansatz aufgetreten. Also ich zumindest kann aus dieser Antwort nicht ableiten, ob ein Ansatz Probleme haben kann. Die andere Antwort besagt zumindest, dass es nicht so gut klingt, wenngleich es auch nicht als falsch abgestempelt wird.

Comment: @Em1: Inzwischen gibt es ja eine Ergänzung die das Problem bei diesem Ansatz thematisiert - was m.E. richtig ist. Der Ansatz oder der Lösungsweg - das ist ja gemeint - hat selbst kein Problem. So verstehe ich die Antwort, aber glasklar wird es nicht gesagt, das stimmt.

Comment: +1 für den ersten Satz... Es kommt in der Tat oft vor (zum Beispiel in Bachelorarbeiten), dass Wörter miteinander verknüpft werden, die eigentlich nicht zusammen passen. Die Sätze sind dann lang, und geschachtelt aber trotzdem irgendwie unscharf und trampelig. Auch Ratgeberbücher machen sowas gern. "Wir haben eine Technik entwickelt..." und eigentlich ist es nur eine simple Idee. Ansatz entwickeln ist ein mildes Beispiel dafür aber es gibt in jedem Fall treffendere Wege, das zu formulieren

Comment: Interessant auch: `**Wer spricht oder schreibt, ruft Bilder auf, und wie beim Gang durch eine gut kuratierte Ausstellung sollten sie aufeinander abgestimmt sein.**` [**Wider die Verwaltung der deutschen Sprache**](http://www.welt.de/debatte/kommentare/article112724211/Wider-die-Verwaltung-der-deutschen-Sprache.html) von Reinhard Marx, WELT Online, erschienen am 12.01.2013.

Answer (score 4):

#### Das Problem ist nicht das "Problem", sondern der "Ansatz".

In dem Text steht, dass ein *Ansatz* das Fliegen (ohne künstliche Hilfen) ermöglicht. Ich denke, dass das Fliegen eher durch Flügel, Katapulte oder kräftige Muskeln ermöglicht werden könnte, aber nicht durch Ansätze. Etwas abstrakter könnte es auch eine Methode oder eine Vorgehensweise sein, wobei die "Vorgehensweise" in den meisten Fällen (so auch hier) zu gekünstelt und nach leeren Phrasen klingt.

Im Gegensatz zu Flügeln, Katapulten, Muskeln, Methoden und Vorgehensweisen kann man Ansätze leider auch nicht entwickeln. Man kann einen Ansatz verwenden oder einem Ansatz folgen, aber entwickeln ist kein passendes Verb.

Ich glaube, das Wort "Methode" würde stattdessen viel besser passen:

> Ich habe **eine Methode** entwickelt, die das Fliegen ohne künstliche Hilfen ermöglicht.

Und den Problem-Satz kann man auch anspruchsvoller gestalten. Statt "Er/Sie hat jedoch einige Probleme." könnte man schreiben:

> Sie **verursacht** jedoch einige Probleme.

Denn weder die Methode noch der Ansatz haben Probleme. Du könntest aber mit einem Problem konfrontiert werden, das auf die Methode oder den Ansatz zurückzuführen ist. Dann hast aber *du* ein Problem, nicht die Methode.

Comment: Interessanter Punkt. Sagen wir ich möchte noch nicht zu konkret werden, würde ich dann `Konzept` benutzen?